# Should I handle ER_DUP_ENTRY before or after INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have Node.js backend application running with MySQL.

I am handling `ER_DUP_ENTRY` on Node.js side, after `INSERT` query executed on current version of server. So I am running `INSERT` and then if MySQL returns that `ER_DUP_ENTRY`, I show up a warning to the user.

I thought getting this error every time from MySQL put an extra load on the database.

My question is, should I have to check database with `SELECT` for DUPLICATE entry and then execute `INSERT` query or is there no problem with the current version?

Comment: Your proposed alternative is reliable only if you lock table for writing. That would certainly put some load on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check before executing the insert query. Just set it up `UNIQUE constraint` over the table for a specific column or combined column(multiple). So whenever you will insert the same data again MySQL will handle this duplicacy.

check the insert query response status. Then you can determine this is success / failed(duplicate or some other error).